# "rm: cannot remove directory" question (i seems to have all rights)

Tags: 14.04, permissions, nginx

I have a folder, which was created by the Docker, but nginx seemed to have no access for it. When i'm trying to access (delete) it manually, i'm getting

> rm: cannot remove '0': Permission denied

error. So here's what is going on:

```
ubuntu@ip:/data/nginx-cache$ ls -l 
total 80 
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr 29 09:48 0

ubuntu@ip:/data/nginx-cache$ rm -rf 0 
rm: cannot remove '0': Permission denied
```

I've been playing with chmod, even tried to set it to 777, but still getting the same error.

PS: please, dont offer **sudo**, i'm trying to get whats going on there. Its looking super strange for me: i have my user's access there, i have my user's group access there, but still "permission denied".

EDIT:

```
lsattr 
 -------------e-- ./0


getfacl 0
# file: 0
# owner: ubuntu
# group: ubuntu user::rwx group::r-x other::r-x
```

Comment: @dsstorefile1 added output to the question

Comment: I believe that the problem is with the permissions of the parent directory, please add the output of `ls -ld /data` and `ls -ld /data/nginx-cache` to your question.

Comment: @mook765 Thanks for answer - i'm pretty sure that parent's owner was the same. Mostly probably i'm wrong, because after i deleted everything and deployed again, everything works fine. My bet is that i didnt restart after `sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)` when installed Docker, so those folders were created by root or something like that. I dont see any other logical explanations.